# Pragmattic use of AutoMapper with Google Protocol Buffers 3

Tags: c#, automapper, protocol-buffers, proto3

I want to use AutoMapper with proto3, but the biggest problem I have is in mapping from a source property that may allow `null` into a proto that never does. When doing such population manually, one must do something like this:

```
var proto = new Proto();

if (source.Field != null)
{
    proto.Field = source.Field;
}
```

I still find it absurd, but that's apparently how it is with proto3.

Anyway, this means that mappings must have conditions on them to ensure `null` values do not propagate to the proto:

```
config
    .CreateMap<Source, Proto>()
    .ForMember(
        x => x.Field,
        options => options.Condition(source => source.Field != null));
```

I can feel this getting old *really* fast as I have a lot of properties in my protos.

What I'm wondering is whether there a way for me to handle this at a higher level of abstraction?

Comment: This might help? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1703#issuecomment-250137782 if it does I will post as answer

Comment: I'm going with this for now, which seems like a simpler way than what's in your link: `.ForAllMembers(options => options.Condition((_, __, sourceMember) => sourceMember != null))`

Comment: Yes, because that solution covers value types too, and I'm guessing you don't need that.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `ForAllOtherMembers` method on the `CreateMap<Source,Proto>` output and specify the condition. This will address your problem of not specifying for each property

Sample code

```
config
    .CreateMap<Source, Proto>()
    .ForAllOtherMembers(
        options => options.Condition((src, dest, srcValue) => srcValue != null));
```